# Checking Condition in HTML

Tags: html, angular

I want to call class on condition of profit or loss so i used greater than and less than signs. Greater than works fine but less than sign gives parse error.

Here's my code:-

```
<td [ngClass]="{'text-green': profitLoss.netSaving > 0},{'text-red': profitLoss.netSaving < 0}">{{profitLoss.netSaving}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<` and `>` symbols are used to open and close html elements. Therefore use `&lt;` and `&gt;`, like so:

```
<td [ngClass]="{'text-green': profitLoss.netSaving &gt; 0, 'text-red': profitLoss.netSaving &lt; 0}">{{profitLoss.netSaving}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<span ng-class="{'text-red': profitLoss.netSaving < 0 }">{{profitLoss.netSaving}} </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular JS provide this functionality in [ng-class Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). In which you can put condition and also assign conditional class.

Use this

```
<td ng-class="{true: 'text-green', false: 'text-red'}[ profitLoss.netSaving > 0]">{{profitLoss.netSaving}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this and try to change the value of "a".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
.text-red{
color:red;
font-size:35px;
}
.text-green{
color:blue;
font-size:25px;
}
</style>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="abc">
<p ng-class="{'text-green': a > 0,'text-red': a < 0}">Have a look at me. Am I able to help you?</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('abc', function($scope) {
    $scope.a = -1;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```